# How can I add objects to an array list using the equals method to exclude similar objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, while-loop, equals

I am trying to create Line objects and add them to an array list. The problem I am having is excluding any lines that are similar to each other. I have already created an equals method that compares two lines to determine if they are equal. I am having trouble using the while loop. I do not have an error message. It compiles just fine. It just will not read from the text file. I am stuck and do not know where else to go from here.

```
public void read( File fileName ) throws Exception
{
    reader = new Scanner(fileName);


    //---------------------
    //Have to read the first number before starting the loop
    int numLines = reader.nextInt();
    lines = new ArrayList <Line> (numLines);

    //This loop adds a new Line object to the lines array for every line in the file read.
    while( reader.hasNext() ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < numLines; i++ ) {
            int x = reader.nextInt();
            int y = reader.nextInt();
            Point beg = new Point(x,y);
            x = reader.nextInt();
            y = reader.nextInt();
            Point end = new Point(x,y);

            String color = reader.next();

              Line l =  new Line( beg, end, color );

              if (l.equals(lines.get(i)))
                  break;
              else
                  lines.add(i, l);


        }
    }

    //Print the action to the console
    System.out.println( "reading text file: " + fileName );
    reader.close();

}
```

Comment: You might be better using a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to discover in the [`Java Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html). You are using the wrong data structure, you can add two different objects in a `List` because the purpose of the list is to be :

> *An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.*

So you have the elements in a given order which is kept when adding objects and you can access objects at any given index in this order.

Now it seems that's not what you want, you'd rather have no duplicate elements rather than an order, right ? If so you need to use a class that implements the Set interface which purpose is to be :

> *A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.*

The java framework contains two implementations of a set :

- [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) : It is a hash based implementations, enjoying the benefits of hashing ensuring a constant access time whatever the size of your collection
- [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) : It is a tree based implementation with a log(n) time for basic operations.

I recommend that you look into the first link I gave, it is the oracle tutorial explaining with much details the Java Collections.

**Your example with a Set**

It's really easy and not that far from using an ArrayList.

1. Change the declaration of your `List` to a `Set` like that (I used a `TreeSet` but you can use any other implementations of a `Set`) :

   ```
   Set<Line> lines = new TreeSet<Line>();
   ```
2. Just use the [`add(E e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) function of the `Set` interface when you want to populate your collection and let it do the job :

   ```
    Line l = new Line(beg.x, beg.y, end.x, end.y);
    lines.add(l);
   ```

**And if you still want to use a `List`**

You can check if an element is in a `List` (or any other `Collection` for that matters) by using the [`contains(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
  lines.contains(l)
```

This will return true if the freshly created `Line` (`l`) is contained in your collection (`lines`).

Comment: Set is likely the correct collection interface to use, but there are more than two implementations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: @kiheru yes you're right, I meant the two most obvious I guess. I correct that right away.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on where to start? I have only worked with arrays and ArrayLists.

Comment: @KelliDavis Well you can start by reading the javadoc links I gave you while I modify your example to use a Set.

Comment: @KelliDavis Have a look and tell me what you think, go through the collections tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html or read a good book about java if you haven't done so already and check the Collection chapter.